# Renegotiate salary after signing a contract due to receiving a better offer

Tags: salary, negotiation, contracts

I have signed a contract to work for a company. Due to some management issue on their side, the start date has been delayed for a month or two. Even though a company is very responsive to my queries, we still don't know when the exact start date will be.

During that time, I am approached by the second company to interview for a senior position. The interview is successful and I am now offered a position which pays a lot more than the one offered by the first company.

Personally, I still want to work for the first company, better location and more interesting projects, but prefer to renegotiate in order to have a better salary. Hence, my question is whether it is possible and professional to contact the first company, let them know that I want to renegotiate the salary since there is another company that offers me a better one.

Comment: I feel this question deviates sufficiently due to the aspect of an indefinitely delayed start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the impression that you're facing the following dilemma:

1. you want to work for company A (starting date unknown, salary acceptable, location excellent) but use contract from company B to improve the salary
2. you want to start working ASAP and company B comes in handy (known starting date, excellent salary, acceptable location)
3. you want to work for company A at all costs (you don't mind waiting, you accept the salary)

Consider the following:

- ad. 1. - if they really want you, they can do much to have you on board (fix starting date, throw more money). But they might as well say *"than go to company B"*. You may win, you may lose.
- ad. 2. - if you communicate your choice to company A wisely, they might try to get you on board. The question is - can they convince you to change your mind?
- ad. 3. - simply bite the bullet and wait for the things to settle down at company A.

Long story short - company A is not flawless here - they shed a considerable amount of uncertainty. Use this as the reason for walk-away message if you chose for option 1 or 2. But if you hear *"then go"*, do your best and not look at company B as a punishment.

I with you to make a satisfactory choice.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider it professional to renegotiate your salary simply because you have a better offer on the table.

But you don't have a start date with C1 and - or so I assume - you do have one with C2. I feel this gives you a legitimate approach to at least open up a dialogue.